# executing a php command inside an `echo("");` comman

Tags: php, forms

I was wondering if it was possible to make a php command echo a whole new php set.

```
<?php
$phpcmd=$_POST["phpcmd"];
echo "<?".$phpcmd."?>";
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" value="<?echo($phpcmd)?>" name="phpcmd">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Try echo '<pre><? . $phpcmd . '?></pre>';

Comment: @Ares Didn't work result is nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using:

```
eval($phpcmd);
```

## BUT...

I would strongly advise you don't, think about the security risks of something like this, a malicious user could cause an awful lot of damage with a script like this.

As the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) state:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Check out [this article](http://clifgriffin.com/2008/12/28/how-to-execute-php-code-in-a-php-string/) for more info on the `eval()` function.

Comment: The page i am using is within my /ftp/ directory and I am the only person with access to it. So I am not worried about people accessing this page.

Comment: And besides I know theres a series of commands that can erase certain inputs from a string.

Comment: So long as you're certain it won't be accessible, just remember if a malicious user wants to find a way, they usually will.

Comment: :D I made a loop around, if anyone trys to run certain commands when submitted the not allowed commands will be replaced by a blank space.